# Select all rows where the sum of column X is greather or equal than Y

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I need to find a group of lots to satisfy X demand for items. I can't do it with aggregate functions, it seems to me that I need something more than a window function, do you know anything that can help me solve this problem?

[image]

For example, if I have a demand for 1 Item, the query should return any lot with a quantity greater than or equal to 1. But if I have a demand for 15, there are no lots with that availability, so it should return a lot of 10 and another with 5 or one of 10 and two of 3, etc.

With a programming language like Java this is simple, but with SQL is it possible? I am trying to achieve it with sales functions but I cannot find a way to add the available quantity of the current row until reaching the required quantity.

```
SELECT  id,VC_NUMERO_LOTE,SF_FECHA_CREACION,SI_ID_M_ARTICULO,VI_CANTIDAD,NEXT, VI_CANTIDAD + NEXT AS TOT FROM (
SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY SF_FECHA_CREACION desc) id ,VC_NUMERO_LOTE,SF_FECHA_CREACION,SI_ID_M_ARTICULO,
VI_CANTIDAD,LEAD(VI_CANTIDAD,1)  OVER (ORDER BY SF_FECHA_CREACION desc) as NEXT FROM PUBLIC.M_LOTE WHERE SI_ID_M_ARTICULO = 44974
AND  VI_CANTIDAD > 0 ) AS T
WHERE   MOD(id, 2) != 0
```

I tried with lead to then sum only odd records but I saw that it is not the way, any suggestions?

Comment: please don't use picture to display table, use text (or table markdown) and include a DDL.

Comment: Your query has nothing to do with your sample data. Please rephrase the question in a way.

Comment: Do you want all solutions or just one solution? i. e. would just LOT-0001 be a valid return for the wanted quantity 1?

Comment: @Turo: I guess, one is enough. All combinations let your output explode very quick when it comes to greater demands.

Comment: We can guess a lot. Some questions: Should this be FIFO (first in/first out) so, the LOT_NUMER ordered by DATE ? What about taking some items of a LOT, is that OK?

Comment: @Luuk It should be FIFO, that's correct. The proposed solutions are perfectly suited. It's really hard to choose the correct answer when they all work.

Comment: The proposed solution don't take the FIFO into account (because you did not mention that in your question) But they can be changed pretty simple to tak into account the FIFO.

Comment: that's right, it's simple to modify the answers to make them fifo, the main question was solved. The difficult thing now is to accept an answer when all helped to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) like this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=124faaccbe442a5637490a81fe413e76)

```
WITH RECURSIVE lots_with_rowcount AS (       -- 1
    SELECT 
        *, 
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY avail_qty DESC) as rowcnt
    FROM mytable
), lots AS (                                 -- 2
    SELECT                                   -- 3
        lot_nr,
        avail_qty,
        rowcnt,
        avail_qty as total_qty
    FROM lots_with_rowcount
    WHERE rowcnt = 1
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT 
        t.lot_nr,
        t.avail_qty,
        t.rowcnt,
        l.total_qty + t.avail_qty           -- 4
    FROM lots_with_rowcount t
    JOIN lots l ON t.rowcnt = l.rowcnt + 1
        AND l.total_qty < --<your demand here>
)
SELECT * FROM lots                          -- 5
```

1. This CTE is only to provide a row count to each record which can be used within the recursion to join the next records.
2. This is the recursive CTE. A recursive CTE contains two parts: The initial `SELECT` statement and the recursion.
3. Initial part: Queries the lot record with the highest `avail_qty` value. Naturally, you can order them in any order you like. Most qty first yield the smallest output.
4. After the `UNION` the recursion part: Here the current row is joined the previous output **AND** as an additional condition: Join only if the previous output doesn't fit your demand value. In that case, the next `total_qty` value is calculated using the previous and the current `qty` value.
5. Recursion end, when there's no record left which fits the join condition. Then you can `SELECT` the entire recursion output.

Notice: If your demand was higher than your all your available quantities in total, this would return the entire table because the recursion runs as long as the demanded is not reached or your table ends. You should add a query before, which checks this:

```
SELECT SUM(avail_qty) > demand FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

I gratefully fiddled around with S-Man's fiddle and found a query, at least simpler to understand

```
select lot_nr, avail_qty, tot_amount from 
(select lot_nr, avail_qty,
  sum(avail_qty) over (order by avail_qty desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as tot_amount,
  sum(avail_qty) over (order by avail_qty desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) - avail_qty as last_amount
from mytable) amounts
where last_amount < 15 -- your amount here
```

so this lists all rows where with the predecesor (in descending order by avail_qty) the limit isn't yet reached

Comment: Nice one. IMHO you don't even need to define the rows window because it's the default for cumulative window functions.

Comment: @S-Man it's a kind of relict, first I had `rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding` for last_amount, and didn't subtract the actual avail_qty. I have the hope this way the optimzer is so smart doing the sum only once, and I could remove a COALESCE...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple old-school PL/pgSQL version that uses a (slow) loop. It returns only the lot numbers as an illustration. Basically what it does is return lot numbers for a particular `item_id` in certain order (that reflects  the required business rules) and allocates the available quantities until the allocated quantity is equal or exceeds the required quantity.

```sql
create function get_lots(required_item integer, required_qty integer) returns setof text as
$$
declare
    r record;
    allocated_qty integer := 0;
begin
for r in select * from lots where item_id = required_item order by <your biz-rule> loop
    return next r.lot_number;
    allocated_qty := allocated_qty + r.available_qty;
    exit when allocated_qty >= required_qty;
end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

-- Use 
select lot_id from get_lots(1, 17) lot_id;
```